# Erlang Dictionary fetch crash

Tags: erlang

EDIT

---

I have two modules and both cause bad args errors when fetching from the dictionary(gen_server state)

Here is code from one module

```
init([ChunkSize, RunningCounter]) ->    
D0 = dict:new(),
D1 = dict:store(chunkSize, ChunkSize, D0),
D2 = dict:store(torrentUploadSpeed, 0, D1),
D3 = dict:store(torrentDownloadSpeed, 0, D2),
TorrentDownloadQueue = queue:new(),
TorrentUploadQueue = queue:new(),
D4 = dict:store(torrentDownloadQueue, TorrentDownloadQueue, D3),
D5 = dict:store(torrentUploadQueue, TorrentUploadQueue, D4),
D6 = dict:store(runningCounter, RunningCounter, D5),
{ok, D6}.
```

I then set_peer_state which sets up a peer dictionary(1 unique for each peer) The dictionary holds the download and upload (queue and speed) and I add this to the main gen_server state(dictionary) So I have the main torrent data in the main dictionary with a dictionary for each peer stored by the peer id.

```
set_peer_state(Id) ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, {setPeerState, Id}).

handle_cast({setPeerState, Id}, State) ->
io:format("In the Set Peer State ~p~n", [dict:fetch(runningCounter, State)]),
Id0 = dict:new(), 
PeerDownloadQueue = queue:new(),
PeerUploadQueue = queue:new(),
Id1 = dict:store(peerDownloadQueue, PeerDownloadQueue, Id0),
Id2 = dict:store(peerUploadQueue, PeerUploadQueue, Id1),
Id3 = dict:store(peerDownloadSpeed, 0, Id2),
Id4 = dict:store(peerUploadSpeed, 0, Id3),
D = dict:store(Id, Id4, State),
    {noreply, D};
```

This seems to work so far. But when I try updating the torrent state it crashes when fetching from the dictionary.

```
handle_cast({updateTorrentDownloadState, Time}, State) ->
% fetch the counter for the speed calculation and queue length
RunningCounter  = dict:fetch(runningCounter, State),
% Fetch the Torrents download queue
TorrentDownloadQueue = dict:fetch(torrentDownloadQueue, State),
io:format("The fetched queue is  ~p~n", [dict:fetch(torrentDownloadQueue, State)]),
% Add the item to the queue (main torrent upload queue)
TorrentDownloadQueue2 = queue:in(Time, TorrentDownloadQueue),
% Get the lenght of the downloadQueue
TorrentDownloadQueueLength = queue:len(TorrentDownloadQueue2),
% If the queue is larger than the running counter remove item 
if
    TorrentDownloadQueueLength >= RunningCounter ->
        % Remove item from the queue
        TorrentDownloadQueue3 = queue:drop(TorrentDownloadQueue2),
        update_torrent_download(TorrentDownloadQueue3, State);

    TorrentDownloadQueueLength < RunningCounter ->
        update_torrent_download(TorrentDownloadQueue2, State)
    end;
```

and here are the 2 internal functions

```
update_torrent_download(TorrentDownloadQueue, State) ->
    % Store the queue to the new torrent dict
    State2  = dict:store(torrentDownLoadQueue, TorrentDownloadQueue, State),
    Speed = calculate_speed(TorrentDownloadQueue, State2),
    State3 = dict:store(torrentDownloadSpeed, Speed, State2),
        {noreply, State3}.

calculate_speed(Queue, State) ->
List = queue:to_list(Queue),
Sum = lists:sum(List),
Count = queue:len(Queue),
ChunkSize = dict:fetch(chunkSize, State),
Speed = (Count * ChunkSize) div Sum,
    {ok, Speed}.
```

Could it be that passing incorrect data to the setters crash the server?
Or does the state get lost along the way?
This way of doing it seems messy with all the new dicts to store in the old dict, is there a better way to handle this data structure(main torrent and data for each peer)?

I know I could make the dictionaries from lists, but it was messing with my mind at the point I was testing this module.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that State is not a dict.

```
1> dict:fetch(runningCounter, not_a_dict).
** exception error: {badrecord,dict}
     in function  dict:get_slot/2
     in call from dict:fetch/2
```

Comment: Thanks. So I use State throughout my module. I thought this was handled by gen serve as the state? Should State be defined in the gen server as a dictionary?

Comment: The gen_server:cast method only passes a message, but the handle_cast takes the message and the State. How does it know what the state is? Ow where do I set this state? I do it in the init method which sets it up, but it doesnt look like it is available in the handle_cast method? Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you're doing the wrong thing somewhere in your program, but the error is not in the code that you shared. State is just a variable, but it's not a dictionary where you're trying to use it, which means you set it incorrectly in some other place.

Comment: How does one set the dictionary if you only fetch from it? I fetch from a dictionary in a handle_call and reply with a calculation result. Then I pass State back at the end of the handle_call. So the State isnt saved as a dictionary. How should I create a dictionary to pass to the { , Response, State} if I only fetch from it? thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your question, please fix the formatting of the code and include all of it.

Comment: I Edited thanks. Im not sure what the issue is. The passed in state isnt always a dictionary.

Comment: Did you try to trace your functions to see how the state is passed from one function to the other one? An alternative could be to use a record for your state, with a "dictionary" field. That way it will be easier for you not to mess the type.

Comment: I would come across the same issue. When I handle a call and fetch from the state it works the first call. but when I use another call it crashes. If I pass in State from the parameters fetch from it and then pass State as is back to the {reply, Response, State} I dont think it knows or stores it as a dictionary.

Comment: In the code you're showing you do not edit the state. The error is not there. Please share the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah, the error is not in the code you've posted. Post the whole thing, including the initialization code.

Answer (score 1):

As YOUR ARGUMENT IS VALID suggested, you're state, at that point of your code, is not a dict.

Answering to your comments, now.

The state of your `gen_server` is set up in the init function, where you return: `{ok, State}.`

Every time your `gen_server` receive a message, an `handle_call` or an `handle_cast` are called (depending if the call is synchronous or asynchronous). Inside these functions, the State that you set up during the init phase can be updated and transformed into ANYTHING. You can't rely on the assumption that the "type" of your initial state is the same during the whole execution of your server.

In other words, if you do something like:

```
init(_Args) -> {ok, dict:new()}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  {ok, completely_new_state}.
```

you've just "converted" your state from a dict into an atom and that (the atom) is what you will get in subsequent calls.

For this kind of errors, the Erlang tracing tool `dbg` is quite helpful, allowing you to see how functions are called and which results are returned. Have a look to this short tutorial to learn how to use it:

http://aloiroberto.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/tracing-erlang-functions/

UPDATE:

What you should do:

```
init(_Args) -> {ok, dict:new()}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  NewState = edit_dict(State),
  {ok, NewState}.
```

Where the edit_dict function is a function which takes a dict and returns an updated dict.

Comment: Great. So Should I make a new dict = State at the beginning of a handle_call, handle_cast function? Will the key value pairs still be the same or whats the point of the state if its type changes?

Comment: Thanks. What or how does the edit dict work? I dont get it. IS this how gen_servers work with their state? Kinda sucks. What about creating a new dict and merging State with it? Or is state not seen as a dictionary? thanks

Comment: The edit_dict function of the example is a helper function that you are supposed to write. Nothing sucks in the way gen_servers manage their state. Once you get the idea behind it, you love it. The merging part is what the edit_dict function is supposed to do. Have a look to the dict:update function. If you share more code, it will be easier for us to comment.

Comment: I have tested this again removing the [ ] from the dictionary values. It still doesnt seem to pass the state around. I can fetch from the dictionary and return , but when I try to fetch from a dictionary and Calculate it there is a crash. I think it is in the order I call these. On the first call it all works, it fetches, but on the next call it crashes. I obviously incorrectly pass the state after the handle call. I updated my question with the code if you dont mind taking a look. thanks a lot.